# Moving object on canvas python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I wanted to get a little square to move to the left 10 pixels every 3 seconds and my code is below. I'm not sure why it only moves once. Some help would be greatly apprecaited!

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
 
root = tk.Tk()
 
WIDTH = HEIGHT = 400
 
x1 = y1 = WIDTH / 2
 
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
 
c1 = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1 + 10, y1 + 10)
c2 = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1 + 10, y1 + 10)
 
 
def draw_rect():
    global c2
    canvas.delete(c2)
    c2 = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1 + 10, y1 + 10, fill="green")
 
 
def del_rect():
    canvas.delete(c1)
    #canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1 + 10, y1 + 10, fill="white", opacity=0.5)

while 1:
    root.update()
    time.sleep(3)
    del_rect()
    x1 -= 10    
    draw_rect()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you provide detail as to what you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Actually the rectangle is moved (although they are not the same rectangle) because the final rectangle shown on the window is filled with green (the initial rectangle is not filled).  If you add `root.update()` before `time.sleep(3)`, you will see the move.

Comment: Thank you! Upon using your suggestion I managed to see it move once. I'm hoping to see it continuously move. I put the bottom 5 lines of my code in the while loop as I updated above but it still only moves once.

Comment: `root.mainloop()` does not return until the window is closed.  Get rid of that line.  Note that the GUI isn't going to be very responsive with this approach, as it will be completely frozen for 3 seconds at a time.  You want to use `.after()` instead for scheduling events for the future.

Comment: canvas has function `move()` - so you don't have to delete rectanlge and create it again.

Answer (score 0):

`mainloop()` runs loop which works until you close window - so it blocks all loop and it is executed only once and it move rectangle only once. In your version you should remove `mainloop()` and it will not block it - and because you use `update()` in loop so it will run correctly.

But you could do this in different way.

You can use `root.after(3000, draw_rect)` to execute `draw_rect()` after 3 seconds. And `draw_rect()` should run again `root.after(3000, draw_rect)` to run it again after another 3 seconds - this way it will loop and it will not blocked by `mainloop()` (`mainloop()` will run `draw_rect()` every 3 seconds)

`Canvas` has function `move(object, dx, dy)` so you don't have to delete rectangle and create it again.

I use `300ms` to run it faster.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- constants --- (PEP8: UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400

# --- functions ---

def move_rect():
    canvas.move(c1, -10, 0)  # move left
    canvas.move(c2, 10, 0)   # move right
    
    # run again after 300ms
    root.after(300, move_rect)  # 300ms = 0.3s  # I use smaller value to make it faster

# --- main ---

x1 = y1 = WIDTH / 2
 
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
 
c1 = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1 + 10, y1 + 10, fill="green")
c2 = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1 + 10, y1 + 10, fill="red")

# run first time after 300ms
root.after(300, move_rect)  # 300ms = 0.3s  # I use smaller value to make it faster
 
root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

Version which uses variables `speed1`, `speed2` to change direction when rectangle is near border.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- constants --- (PEP8: UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400

# --- functions ---

def move_rect():
    global speed1
    global speed2
    
    #x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(c1)
    pos = canvas.coords(c1)
    if speed1 < 0 :
        if pos[0] < 10:
            speed1 = -speed1
    else:
        if pos[2] > WIDTH-10:
            speed1 = -speed1
        
    #x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(c2)
    pos = canvas.coords(c2)
    if speed2 < 0:
        if pos[0] < 10:
           speed2 = -speed2
    else:
        if pos[2] > WIDTH-10:
            speed2 = -speed2
        
    canvas.move(c1, speed1, 0)  # move left    
    canvas.move(c2, speed2, 0)  # move right
    
    # run again after 30ms
    root.after(30, move_rect)  # 30ms = 0.03s  - I uses smaller value to make it faster

# --- main ---

x1 = y1 = WIDTH / 2

speed1 = -10
speed2 = +10

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
 
print(dir(canvas)) 
c1 = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1 + 10, y1 + 10, fill="green")
c2 = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1 + 10, y1 + 10, fill="red")

# run first time after 300ms
root.after(300, move_rect)  # 300ms = 0.3s  - I uses smaller value to make it faster
 
root.mainloop()
```